# CloudWatch auto alarm deletion executing multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a piece of python script that is running in an AWS Lambda function that deletes a CloudWatch alarm when an EC2 instance is going to the Stopped state.

```
elif    'source' in event and event['source'] == 'aws.ec2' and event['detail']['state'] == 'stopped':
        instanceID = event['detail']['instance-id']
        GetAlarmNamePrefix = "AutoAlarm-" + instanceID
        print(GetAlarmNamePrefix)
        for instance in instanceID:
            print("deleting alarms for instance :" + instanceID)
            AlarmNamePrefix = GetAlarmNamePrefix
            response = cloudwatch.describe_alarms(AlarmNamePrefix=AlarmNamePrefix,)
            alarm_list = []
            if 'MetricAlarms' in response:
                for alarm in response['MetricAlarms']:
                    alarm_name = alarm['AlarmName']
                alarm_list.append(alarm_name)
                print(alarm_list)
                cloudwatch.delete_alarms(AlarmNames=alarm_list)
```

This code is deleting the alarms fine but when I look at the Lambda function's execution logs in the CloudWatch Log Group I could see there is a huge number of events created for the same CloudWatch alarm multiple times.

Please help me to fix this code.

[image: Please see the screenshot attached for from log groups]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these lines:

```py
        instanceID = event['detail']['instance-id']
        GetAlarmNamePrefix = "AutoAlarm-" + instanceID
        print(GetAlarmNamePrefix)
        for instance in instanceID:
            print("deleting alarms for instance :" + instanceID)
```

In theory, it is looping through each instance. However:

- The `print()` statement is printing `instanceID` rather than `instance`
- Nothing in the loop is actually referring to `instance`

The fact is, `instanceID` is a string that **contains one Instance ID**, as can be seen when printing `GetAlarmNamePrefix`.

Therefore, you can remove the `for` loop.

It is possible that multiple events are being passed to the Lambda function. However, the section of your code that extracts the `event` is not shown, so I can't comment on whether that should be changed.

Comment: Thanks John for the help.